# How to make a multi platform container for a .NET application

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a .NET 7 app that I want to run it on a raspberry pi compute module 4 inside a container.

I have seen that the compute module 4 supports the arm64 architecture and thus my image should be built for arm64.

The idea behind the flashing process is that I would build and push the image to a container registry and the pi would pull and run the image.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Stage 2: Create the final image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS runtime

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

If I try to build like that :

```
docker build -t app --platform linux/amd64 .
```

It works and of course can run since I am using a linux distro.

But if I try to build for arm64 with:

```
docker build -t beacon --platform linux/arm64 .
```

I get an error on line 8, indicating:

```
> [build 4/4] RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out:
0.285 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   6 |     COPY . .
   7 |     
   8 | >>> RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
   9 |     
  10 |     # Stage 2: Create the final image
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Based on the message, I am assuming that there is a problem with the **dotnet CLI**?

Shouldn't be the case that the **Dockerfile** is platform independent and **the platform configuration eg --platform should build the image for the specified distribution?**

My questions are:

1. Do you see any potential issues with the Dockerfile or the command I am using to build for arm64?
2. Is there a better way to build an image for arm64, push it and let the pi pull and run it from my way?

### Edit:

The solution was to use **buildx**, I am attaching a **Makefile** that supports **both production and development stages**

```
setup_builder:
    docker buildx create --use
    docker buildx create --use --name app_builder --use
    docker buildx inspect app_builder --bootstrap

build_development:
    docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t app:latest . --load

build_production:
    docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t app:latest .

compose:
    docker-compose up
```

And this is the docker compose I use to run it locally:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  my-service:
    image: app:latest
    volumes:
      - a_file:/app/a_file
      - another_file:/app/another_file
      - yet_another_file:/app/yet_another_file
    network_mode: host
```

Comment: Your dockerfile appears correct for a multiplatform build, can you verify that the base images support the target architecture? P.S. i remember doing something of this sort when trying to run a display link driver on my rp

Comment: I believe issue is due to building on Windows and then deploying on Linux Arm64.  See : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/144445/wine-arm64-install-for-raspberry-pi-os-64-bit-to-run-windows-for-arm-native-appl  You may not have the correct drivers installed on Windows.  See : https://github.com/worproject/RPi-Windows-Drivers

Comment: Have you taken a look at docker's `buildx` feature?

Comment: What is the `-t` parameter here? I don't recognise that one.

Comment: @jdweng No, this image contains all the required components to build

Comment: Which version of the .NET SDK are you using? The [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-multiplatform-container-support/) that announced support for `--platform` and `buildx`says they'll be released in .NET 8 and .NET 7.0.300. Which even VS 17.8 Preview hadn't installed, so I'm installing it now

Comment: I found the solution, I used buildx and it can now build for both arm and amd64, will add a makefile to showcase how I approached it. Thank you all!